# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting the "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error whenever I try to use the global variable from a different component, in this case when I use the global variable from Brewery.js in Random.js

Brewery.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.url = "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries";
    fetch(window.url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }
```

Random.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(window.url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that the text you're receiving back isn't JSON. One reason that might be is that you're not checking to see whether the request succeeded before trying to parse the result. If the server responds with HTML instead of JSON when the request fails (probably a standard error page), you'll get exactly that error. You need to check `response.ok`. (It's not just you, this is a **very** common error, so common I wrote it up [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)

Comment: So: `.then(response => { if (!response.ok) { throw new Error("error here"); } return response.json(); })`

Comment: Two other notes on that code, FWIW: 1. You're not handling errors, which you really should be: Add a `.catch`. 2. If you make your parameter name in the last `then` handler `breweries` instead of `data`, you can use shorthand property notation: `.then(breweries => { this.setState({breweries}); })`

Comment: I've fixed the code the way you said; however I'm still getting the same error on the "return response.json(); })" line

Comment: That tells you that the server is not sending back JSON even on success. Look in the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see what it's sending back instead, and look at the documentation of the endpoint you're calling to make sure you're providing the right information to it.

Comment: When I look in the network tab I can see the API call with the items fetched. The API works since if I put the link directly into the fetch of the Random.js it works. I believe there's a problem with the way I'm handling the global variable "url"

Comment: Creating a global in `componentDidMount` is definitely poor practice. Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Well I've been trying to find a way to declare a global variable for the API Url so that I can use it in the other components I have. I have also created a new component where I only have this global variable declared and exported and then used it in both Brewery.js and Random.js; however I ran into the same problem that I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

You've said that the first block (Brewery.js) works, but the second (Random.js) doesn't.

It's certainly poor practice to create a global variable in `componentDidMount` and rely on it in another component. Clearly, what's happening is the second component is mounting before the first, so `window.url` is `undefined`, and so you end up requesting `"undefined"` instead of the correct URL.

First, don't repeat yourself. Instead, have a single function that gets breweries, and reuse it:

```
function getBreweries() {
  return fetch(window.url)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        });
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

You might even make it handle setting state:

```
function loadBreweriesIntoState() {
  return fetch(window.url)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        });
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(breweries => {
        component.setState({breweries});
    })
    .catch(error => {
        component.setState({error: "Error loading the list of breweries."});
    });
}
```

Then, in the two components (Random.js and Brewery.js), use that function rather than repeating the logic.

Which brings us to: How do you make that function available to both components?

Two answers:

1. If you're using modules (which I strongly recommend), put it in a module they both use:

   `loadBreweriesIntoState.js`:

   ```
   export default function loadBreweriesIntoState() {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   `Brewery.js`:

   ```
   import loadBreweriesIntoState from "./loadBreweriesIntoState.js";

   // ...

       componentDidMount() {
           loadBreweriesIntoState(this);
       }
   ```

   `Random.js`:

   ```
   import loadBreweriesIntoState from "./loadBreweriesIntoState.js";

   // ...

       componentDidMount() {
           loadBreweriesIntoState(this);
       }
   ```
2. If you're not using modules, put it in a script that you include prior to the two component scripts (in development) and set up to be included before them in your bundle (for production).

Those two options apply if you want to keep the logic in the components instead, too: Just make `url` an export in some kind of `Config.js` (or a global that it creates).